# Can't expand hidden lines in Notepad++, Triangles disappear

Tags: notepad++

I'm writing a file that includes both HTML & JavaScript.

Just today I found that I could hide rows by selecting them and right-clicking the line numbers (select hide rows). Green triangles appear that allow you to un-hide them again.

Cool! I can finally colapse huge sections of html while set to JS language..

Except the green triangles disappear and a gap in line numbers persists!! You need to exit notepad to get them back.

Other forums like notepad++'s don't seem to be understanding the issue.

edit:
Here's how i reproduce it - hide a few sections of lines, now expand one of the sections, all of the triangles disappear. I re-added the two hidden sections for the picture to show a correctly functioning hidden section.

[image]

Comment: I have never faced this issue, could you add some sample lines that allow us to reproduce it?

Comment: What style have you setup ? What version are you using ?

Comment: What do you mean by style? language is JS because that's what most of the file is. I'm not using the 1-5 style token, nor do I have any experience using them.   v7.3.2

Comment: I mean which theme are you using ? Check in settings -> style configurator.

Comment: I'll update the version now. Why would the theme matter? Its a twilight based theme with some color adjustments..

Comment: Same issue exists on newest version of notepad++ (7.5.4 x64)

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue on N++ 7.5.3 on Windows 32 bit.

Answer (score 3):

Another way around this is to select text above and below the hidden lines as a block, then use the context menu to change the formatting to something like UPPERCASE.  This causes the hidden text to reappear, at which point you can issue an Undo command to put the text back as it was.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may simply be a bug...

I made a post on Notepad++ forums and may have gotten some attention on the subject:

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15027/hidden-line-triangles-disappear

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed this issue but haven't found a real solution yet. As a work around, looking at your example there is an line gap from lines 124-127 indicating a group of hidden lines missing their chevrons. If you highlight and hide lines 123 to 128, that is the visible boundaries of the hidden lines missing their chevrons, then new chevrons will appear for this second, encompassing set of lines, which, when unhidden, will reveal the first hidden set of lines, 125-127 that were originally missing chevrons.

Comment: Yes, this is the work around. I have had no luck in getting Notepad to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

I have never found a way to "unhide" lines when they were hidden.  I tested and found that they seem only to last for the session you are currently editing.  If I hide several lines and then save and close my file, upon reopening this file all of my previously hidden lines are "unhidden" or just view-able again.

Answer (score 0):

Just clicking on the green triangle in the margin worked for me, as explained [here](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/10271/hide-lines-how-to-show-again/3).